# Apache Camel - Process JSON using REST service

Tags: json, apache-camel

I'd like to process a subset of a JSON within an Apache Camel route. For example, given the following JSON message:

```
{
  "text_1": "some text input",
  "text_2": "some other text input"
}
```

I would like to extract a JSON string `"some text input"` and `POST` the value to a web service. Following this I would like to replace the existing text with the result. Let's assume the response from the web service was `"some text output"`, then I would like to transform the JSON within a Camel route as follows:

```
{
  "text_1": "some text output",
  "text_2": "some other text input"
}
```

My understanding is the `content enricher` and `aggregator` patterns might be able to achieve this. Guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [Content Enricher EIP](https://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) in combination with [Message Translator EIP](https://camel.apache.org/message-translator.html) is a good choice.

You can do something similar to this:

```
from("direct:json")
    .unmarshal(json)
    .enrich("direct:callService", (original, response) -> {
        original.getIn().getBody(Map.class).put(
                "text_1",
                response.getIn().getBody(String.class)
        );
        return original;
    })
    .marshal(json)
    .to("log:result");

from("direct:callService")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
    .setBody(simple("${body[text_1]}"))
    .to("http4://httpbin.org/post");
```

Full example can be found here https://gist.github.com/bedlaj/aaa5c80ed8cc4c64308e7fbd1d7d57f1

Comment: Thank you kind sir!